# How to retain state in Rx without the scan function

Tags: swift, kotlin, rx-java, state-machine, rx-swift

I'm working on porting some of my View Models into (rough) Finite State Machines as my UI tends to fit that pattern rather well (Mealy/Moore, don't care for the purpose of this question). Additionally, when done well - state machines really clean up testing - as they prohibit certain test permutations from ever happening.

My current view models use RxSwift (and RxKotlin - depending on the app), and the underlying use cases (database calls, network calls, etc) also use Rx (hence why I need to stay in that ecosystem).

What I've discovered is that Rx is awesome, State Machines are awesome --> Rx + State Machines seem to be a bit of a hash to do anything non-trivial. For example, I know I can use the `.scan` operator to retain some state, IF my state machine was entirely synchronous (for example, something roughly like this in Swift):

```
enum Event {
    case event1
    case event2
    case event3
}

enum State {
    case state1
    case state2
    case state3

    func on(event: Event) -> State {
        switch (self, event) {
        case (.state1, .event1):
            // Do something
            return .state2

        case (.state2, .event2):
            // Do something
            return .state3

        default:
            return self // (or nil, or something)
        }
    }
}

func foo() -> Observable<State> {
    let events = Observable<Event>.of(.event1, .event2, .event3)
    return events.scan(State.state1) { (currentState, event) -> State in
        return currentState.on(event)
    }
}
```

But, what can I do if the return from my `State.on` function is an Observable (like a network call or something that takes a long time, which is already in Rx)?

```
enum State {
    case notLoggedIn
    case loggingIn
    case loggedIn
    case error

    func on(event: Event) -> Observable<State> {
        switch (self, event) {
        case (.notLoggedIn, .event1):
            return api.login(credentials)
                .map({ (isLoggedIn) -> State in
                    if isLoggedIn {
                        return .loggedIn
                    }
                    return .error
                })
                .startWith(.loggingIn)

        ... other code ...

        default:
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried making the `.scan` operator take in an Observable accumulator, but the result of this code is that the state machine is subscribed to or run too many times. I guess because it runs on each state in the observable that is accumulating.

```
return events.scan(Observable.just(State.state1)) { (currentState, event) -> Observable<State> in
    currentState.flatMap({ (innerState) -> Observable<State> in
        return innerState.on(event: event)
    })
}.flatMap { (states) -> Observable<State> in
    return states
}
```

I think, if I could manage to cleanly pull the `state` variable back in, the simplest implementation could look like this:

```
return events.flatMapLatest({ (event) -> Observable<State> in
    return self.state.on(event: event)
        .do(onNext: { (state) in
            self.state = state
        })
})
```

But, pulling from a private state variable into an observable stream, and updating it - well, not only is it ugly, I feel like I'm just waiting to be hit by a concurrency bug.

---

Edit: Based on feedback from Sereja Bogolubov - I've added a Relay and come up with this code - still not great, but getting there.

```
let relay = BehaviorRelay<State>(value: .initial)
...

func transition(from state: State, on event: Event) -> Observable<State> {
    switch (state, event) {
    case (.notLoggedIn, .event1):
        return api.login(credentials)
            .map({ (isLoggedIn) -> State in
                if isLoggedIn {
                    return .loggedIn
                }
                return .error
            })
            .startWith(.loggingIn)

    ... other code ...

    default:
        return self
    }
}

return events.withLatestFrom(relay.asObservable(), resultSelector: { (event, state) -> Observable<State> in
    return self.transition(from: state, on: event)
        .do(onNext: { (state) in
            self.relay.accept(state)
        })
}).flatMap({ (states) -> Observable<State> in
    return states
})
```

The relay (or replay subject or whatever) is updated in a `doOnNext` from the result of the state transition... This still feels like it could cause a concurrency problem, but not sure what else would work.

Comment: Does this have any relevance? https://github.com/NoTests/RxFeedback.swift

Comment: I've seen RxFeedback before and it looks interesting - but it looks a little over-designed for what I need (granted - maybe it's exactly as much code as needed for this convoluted problem, I'm not sure). I'm looking for a simpler solution first, and would maybe try that a bit later - where possible, I'm trying not to make people using my code learn too many new libraries/paradigms   :)

Comment: The real trickery that I meant is that internally, [they use a `ReplaySubject(1)`](https://github.com/NoTests/RxFeedback.swift/blob/2f16ef3ca13aeb6dcce57ec5101cfb5ef6d43cc0/Sources/RxFeedback/ObservableType%2BRxFeedback.swift#L34-L35) (in any other Rx world, a BehaviorSubject) to retain state while also exposing it to the outside world.

Comment: "but the result of this code is that the state machine is subscribed to or run too many times" yes, Rx invokes every operator for each subscriber. If you want to do this operation only once, and share result between multiple subscriber, you can use [`.share()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/774276961d4d6e42fb3543e0340c2fe087ea4601/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#sharing-subscription-and-share-operator) operator

Comment: @TolgaOkur I tried that briefly, but ran into some issues - but I might have put the share at the wrong locations. Porting my code to RxKotlin actually made it yet less verbose and solved those problems (via a relay and 1 flatmap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to be entirely sync to maintain arbitrary complex state.
Yes, there are ways to achive needed behavior without `scan`. How about the [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html), where `other` is your current state (i.e. a separate `Observable<MyState>`, but you would need `ReplaySubject<MyState>` under the hood).

Let me know if you need more details.

---

Proof of concept, javascript:

```
const source = range(0, 10);
const state = new ReplaySubject(1);
const example = source.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(state), // that's the way you read actual state
  map(([n, currentState]) => {
    state.next(n); // that's the way you change the state
    return ...
  })
);
```

Please be aware that more sophisticated cases (like race conditions risky) might require something at least as complex as [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) and approp. `Scheduler`'s in place.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - could you provide some basic code that I could test out? I've been debating using subjects/relays under the hood - but at this point, -working- is better than elegant but failing   :)

Comment: I've made an edit to my code based on your feedback - without littering state updates everywhere, is there a cleaner way than the doOnNext?

Comment: Nope. And shouldn't actually be: that's the right way to separate responsibilities within Rx concept.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use something like this (relay to hold state, with just a withLatestFrom/FlatMap) and it has sufficed "so far"

Answer (score 1):

I think Elm's system can come in handy here. In Elm, the reducer that you pass into the system doesn't just return state, it also returns a "command" which in our case would be a `Observable<Event>` (not an RxSwift.Event, but your Event enum.) This command isn't stored in the scan's state, but rather it is subscribed to outside the scan and its output is fed back into the scan (through a Subject of some sort.) Tasks that require cancelling would observe the current state and start and stop operation based on the state.

There are several libraries in the RxSwift ecosystem that help simplify these sort of things. The two primary ones are, [ReactorKit](https://github.com/ReactorKit/ReactorKit) and [RxFeedback](https://github.com/NoTests/RxFeedback.swift). And there are several others...

For a simple example of what I'm talking about, check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/a102153cb29be9c4354e0bbdebf1d5ca). This sort of system allows your Moore machine to fire off an action upon entering a state which could potentially cause 0..n new input events.

Comment: Thanks, I did look into Elm arch andsome of those libraries - but as mentioned above, I was trying to go as simple as possible, just to make maintainability easier for future generations :)

Comment: No problem. The gist I linked to is barely over 30 lines of code. I consider that pretty simple.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, the gist was great! But using a withLatestFrom and a relay, I ended up with a pretty tight piece of code in both Swift and Kotlin... However, if I run into problems in the near future, I'll be revisiting your more encapsulated Store solution!